# passport-linkedin callback does not work

Tags: javascript, node.js, linkedin-api, passport.js

I'm using passport-linkedin to integrate LinkedIn account in my project. Problem is when linkedin email does not found in my database, I need to display linkedin account information in callback function.

**passport.js**

```
passport.use(new LinkedInStrategy({
    consumerKey: '12121',
    consumerSecret: '1212121',
    callbackURL: "/auth/linkedin/callback",
    profileFields: ['id', 'first-name', 'last-name', 'email-address', 'headline']
  },
  function(token, tokenSecret, profile, done) {
        auth.findOne({ username: profile.emails[0].value }).then(function (err, user) {
            if (!user) {
                return done(null, profile);
            } else {
                return done(null, user);
            }
        }, function (err) {
            return done(err, null);
        })
    }
));
```

routes.js

```
app.get('/auth/linkedin/callback', 
    passport.authenticate('linkedin', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
        function(req, res) {
        winston.error('linkedInfo: %s', req);
        res.redirect('/');
  });
```

In routes.js, I want to display all of json data from LinkedIn. But nothing display as not working at all.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to check would be ensuring that you are requesting the `r_basicprofile` and `r_emailaddress` member permissions during the OAuth process, if you want to return a member's email address.

The entire call could be failing (and obscured to you via the Passport layer) as a result of you not having the necessary permissions to request all of the fields you are asking for.